# Removing index by appending and using the range function only

Tags: python, append

I need help with the following code. I can only use the append method and range function (no slicing or any other method.

Here is my code:

```
def length(my_list):

    result = 0
    for char in my_list:
        result += 1

    return result

def remove(my_list, position):

    new_list2 = [] # Create a new list
    length2 = length(my_list) # Calls upon the length function

    if position < 0:
        new_list2.append(my_list[position])

    for r in range(length2):
        if r == position:
            new_list2.append(my_list[position])

    if position > length2:
        new_list2.append(my_list)

    return new_list2

str_list5 = ['f','i','r','e']
new_list = remove(str_list5, 2)
print(new_list)
new_list = remove(str_list5, -1)
print(new_list)
new_list = remove(str_list5, 10)
print(new_list)
```

Output should be:

['f', 'i', 'e']

['i', 'r', 'e']

['f', 'i', 'r']

If anyone can show me where I'm going wrong that would be great. I know I'm missing one little bit I think.

Thanks

Comment: can only use range and append to do what? what isn't working? what does it do?

Comment: yeah I can only use the range function and append method. It does ['r'], ['e'], ['f', 'i', 'r', 'e']

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop, you're only appending if the `index` you're on is the one you want to remove, this is the opposite to what you want

```
    if r == position:
```

should be

```
    if r != position:
```

---

At the same time, you can use `min`, to make sure that if your position is too large, you remove the last character

```
  if r != min(position, length2 - 1):
```

---

And if you're using a negative index, then you should just convert this into a non negative index to compare against, so all in all...

```
def remove(my_list, position):

    new_list2 = [] # Create a new list
    length2 = length(my_list) # Calls upon the length function

    index_to_remove = min(position, length2 -1)
    if position < 0:
        index_to_remove = max(length2 + position, 0)

    for r in range(length2):
        if r != index_to_remove:
            new_list2.append(my_list[r])

    return new_list2
```

Comment: I like the way you have provided it above, but I'm not allowed to use the min and max function. The only functions I'm allowed to use are the range and str functions.

Comment: @zeps - the logic behind `min` and `max` are pretty simple, you should easily be able to write them yourself, returning the smallest,largest of the two values you pass into the function

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to achive, but maybe you can do it in more elegant way:

```
my_list = ['f','i','r','e']

def remove(my_list, index):
    b = my_list.copy()
    del b[index]
    return b

remove(my_list, -1)
```

output:

```
['f', 'i', 'r']
```

1. You don't need to create your own `length` function. Use built-in `len`.
2. You can delete element from list by index using `del` (or [pop()](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)).
3. Because you don't want to change your first list, create it's copy by `copy()`.
4. After that you can add some additional logic if you need.

For example:

```
if position > len(b):
```

---

If you can use `append` only, can we go this way:

```
def remove(my_list, position):
    b = []
    for ind, el in enumerate(my_list):
        if ind != position:
            b.append(el)
```

and add some logic for `position > length` and `position<length`.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use the len method, that's why I'm calling upon another function. the append method is all I'm allowed to use.

Comment: @zeps Ah, ok. I add one more example

Comment: I managed to get the first part working as per my original question but, I can't seem to get the output of ['i', 'r', 'e'] and ['f', 'i', 'r'] from my if statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
def evaluate_index(l,i):
    leng = len_function(l)
    if i < 0:
        return leng+i
    elif i>=leng:
        return leng-1
    else:
        return i

def len_function(l): # You cant use len, so lets make one
    increment = 0
    for i in l:
        increment +=1
    return increment

def remove(l,p):
    new_list = []
    [new_list.append(l[i]) for i in range(len_function(l)) if i!=evaluate_index(l,p)]
    return new_list


>>> print(remove(['f','i','r','e'],2))
>>> ['f', 'i', 'e']
```

You have though very strange indexing. If there is -1, it means last element, but you have it like 0 index. I did it according to standard python functioning